# CSS disable scale animation of part of the icon

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to disable the scale animation of :before part of the icon class when the button is hovered to make it look good.
For now, the entire icon is scaling so it makes the arrow looks aweful when on hover state ...

[**Codepen link**](https://codepen.io/AniminD/pen/zYrZmwY)

**HTML**

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="button"><href="#">Button<span class="arrow-right icon"></span> </div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.section {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
padding-left: 25px;
padding-right: 85px;
  border: 2px #009EE2 solid;
  float: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #009EE2;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .9em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
  display: flex;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 1em;
  outline: none;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 -125px;
  width: auto;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
  color: #009EE2;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button:hover .arrow-right.icon {
  transition: color 0.4s, background-color 0.4s;
   color: #009EE2;
   animation: expand 1.5s;
  -webkit-animation: expand 1.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.arrow-right.icon {
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: currentColor;
}

.arrow-right.icon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: 1px;
  top: -5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-top: solid 1px currentColor;
  border-right: solid 1px currentColor;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

@keyframes expand {
  
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
  }
    100% {
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes expand {
  
 
  0% {
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
  }
  60% {
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
  }
    100% {
    transform: scaleX(1.5);
  }
}
```

This is my first stack overflow, thank you in advance for you help (:

Comment: You can not “disable” such transformation for child elements/content; at most, you can _reverse_ them accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Any idea on what would eventually be the trick to do what I'm trying to attempt @CBroe ?

Comment: Create the arrow the other way around, maybe? Use `.arrow-right.icon` itself to make the right angle (that when rotated creates the point of the arrow), and use `:before` for the actual line … then you could scale the latter separately.

Comment: Thank you again. I did not manage to do it that way but just disabled :before display on hover and add the same element to appear when hovered !

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :
[https://codepen.io/VweMWoz](https://codepen.io/pranavraghaw1/pen/VweMWoz)

```
const tl = gsap.timeline({paused: true});
tl.from(
    ".gsap-swipe",
    {
      y: 20,
      x: 20,
      rotate: -40,
      duration: 3,
      transformOrigin: '30% 80%',
      ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.5),
    }, 0
  )
  .fromTo(
    ".swipe",
    {
      xPercent: -100
    },
    {
      duration: 1,
      xPercent: 100,
      ease: Sine.easeInOut,
      stagger: {
        each: 0.15
      }
    }, 0
  )
  .from(
    ".maskSwipe",
    {
      xPercent: -100,
      ease: Sine.easeInOut
    },
    0.4
  )
  .from(
    "#hello",
    {
      duration: 1.5,
      drawSVG: "0%"
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".swoop",
    {
      duration: 2,
      drawSVG: "0%"
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".line",
    {
      drawSVG: "0%",
      duration: 0.5,
      stagger: {
        each: 0.2
      }
    },
    1
  )
  .from(
    ".shape",
    {
      scale: 0,
      duration: 1.3,
      transformOrigin: "50% 50%",
      rotate: '+=random(-60, 60)',
      ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(1, 0.8),
      stagger: {
        each: 0.2
      }
    },
    0.2
  );

// ScrubGSAPTimeline(tl);

let hover = document.querySelector('.js-hover');

hover.addEventListener('mouseover', playTl);
hover.addEventListener('mouseout', resetTl);

function playTl(){
  tl.timeScale(1.25).restart();
}

function resetTl(){
  tl.progress(0).pause();
}
```